# Force file download with PHP: corrupted files, have tried several solutions

Tags: php, file, download

This has been posted, but  I've tried lot of solutions found on SO and more (like this: http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download)

I basically have this:

```
{       
    $filePath = '../public/myfile.png';
    $fileName = basename($filePath);
    $fileSize = filesize($filePath);


    if (!is_file) {
        die("File not found");
    } else {                        
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= " . $fileName);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($filePath);
    }
}
```

Files are recognized and downloaded, but .PNGs are empty and .DOCs are corrupted (and Word asks me to fix the file, then it's ok). I have tried also PDFs, and no problem with that.

I trues to put all sort of options (Pragma, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Length, etc.), still downloaded files but corrupted in some way...

Did you ever had my problem? Please consider I'm on IIS 7.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have debug on try opening one of the corrupted files with a text-editor and see if there are errors printed

Comment: Is the wrong size? That's probably the main reason for corruption; the other is php warnings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the downloaded files with a plain text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). At the top you will find a PHP Error notice, it will tell you what's going wrong.

The error is probably "session already send". Then add `ob_start();` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Oh, my... "Use of undefined constant is_file - assumed 'is_file'", I forgot the filepath in the function! Ok, I need a stop... :-) 
Thanks very much, you just saved my day!

Comment: You may also want to use this trick to see if there was any whitespace at the beginning of the file.  It will stop images from properly loading in everything but photoshop.