# Corrupted images when downloading from RapidShare

Tags: php, image, corruption, rapidshare

I offload a lot of my sites uploads to RapidShare for storage. I then have a script that when accessed by a user wanting to download a file, downloads it from RapidShare using their API and serves it to the user. Here's the relevant code in the script that serves the file:

```
// Stream file to user
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $result->name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . $result->size);

$url = 'https://' . $host . '/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download';
$url .= '&login=login';
$url .= '&password=mypass';
$url .= '&fileid=' . $result->rs_fileid;
$url .= '&filename=' . $result->name;

$handle = fopen($url, 'rb');
if(!$handle) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to open file handle');
}

while(!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 1024*1024);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

fclose($handle);
```

This works fine for all the files I've tested except for images. When the images are downloaded, they're corrupt. Windows Photo Viewer can't open the image and neither can programs like Photoshop.

Weird thing is, if I download a .exe and run it, everything works fine. It's not corrupt. It only happens with images as far as I can tell. I've also tested it with .pdf's.

To make it weirder, if I look at the filesize of the original image (2,882 bytes) and then the filesize of the image downloaded through this script, they're the same. The filesizes for both are 2,882 bytes. But the image is still corrupt.

What could be the cause of this and the solution? It's not like I'm adding any binary data to the file as it's downloaded. :/

Thanks.

Edit: Forgot to mention, if I download the file straight from RapidShare without going through the script the image is fine and isn't corrupt. So it must be the script at fault here.

Comment: How do the md5sums of the files compare?  Can you give us an example of the original and the mangled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my [answer for a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10980789/22470), I'm pretty sure there will be some notice at the beginning of your files!

Comment: That was it, thanks. Had this at the start: `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant resp - assumed 'resp' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php</b> on line <b>53</b><br />` Forgot a `$` in front of a variable. :p

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your code, there is no need for the `header()` stuff and file_put/get_contents is much sleeker:

```
$url = 'https://' . $host . '/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download';
$url .= '&login=login';
$url .= '&password=mypass';
$url .= '&fileid=' . $result->rs_fileid;
$url .= '&filename=' . $result->name;

file_put_contents($result->name, file_get_contents($url));
```

---

When you have memory problems, use [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), easy to use.

Comment: I'm not saving the file from RapidShare though. I'm streaming it to the user. The headers make sure the users browser recognises it's a download and then the file from RapidShare is echo'd out in chunks.

Comment: Ah, ok! So simply use `echo file_get_contents($url);` instead of the "ugly" `fread()` stuff.

Comment: That's actually what I was doing originally. Unfortunately, `file_get_contents()` loads the entire file into memory before echo'ing it to the client. I'm serving large downloads (some a few GB in size) and if I used `file_get_contents()` I'd have a GB file loaded into memory. Hence I have to use the more error prone method of serving it in chunks, so I only have that chunk in memory. Thanks though. :)

Comment: if you have large files use mod_xsendfile https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ it is very useful and easy to use!